# NSInvocationOperation Question

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsthread

I would like to know how to remove duplicate nsoperations, i.e is there a way to check the nsoperation queue and see if I am making a duplicate request?

Basically, I am requesting images depending on the iphone screen rotation. When the view is loaded the shouldautorate is called twice.

```
If(rotation==portrait){
  request portrait image.
}
```

The issue is that shoud autorotate will be checked twice. And on both ocassions, it will turn out to be portrait hence requesting the same image twice. Anyone with a good idea? I forgot to mention I am using a queue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW, better answer:**

Don't use the `shouldAutorotate...` method. It only *asks* whether a rotation is allowed to happen. This may happen any time and may not necessarily lead to a rotation. Instead, use `willRotate...` or `didRotate...`, as these methods are only invoked *exactly once* and only if the rotation actually happens.

Your operation will then be added only once.

---

**OLD, but not false answer:**

How about using a instance variable to remember the last seen rotation? Like so:

```
if (rotation != lastSeenRotation) {
    // REQUEST image here
}
```

Comment: Yer I thought about that but is that not hacky ?

Comment: Oh well nvm, will stick to that. It is way simpler than checking my queue and seeing if I have duplicates. Prevention is better.

Comment: I was told we should not be using the shouldautorotate method and use the willrotate or didrotate method.

Comment: definitely, use the latter. The reason is simple: the first one will ASK for a rotation, but does not actually require the rotation to happen. The latter two actually PERFORM the rotation. And (clumsy me) in those cases you also don't need the check: the rotation action happens only once. I'll adjust my post accordingly.